# datatables bootstrap modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am trying to get a click to open editable content of my dyniamically generated rows in modals, using datatables plugin.

I see an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined.

I am using the following files apart from jquery and bootstrap.min.js:

```
<!-- Datatables -> these files are required to make the table headers fixed, sortable etc-->

<link href="../../../vendors/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../../vendors/datatables.net-buttons-bs/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../../vendors/datatables.net-fixedheader-bs/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../../vendors/datatables.net-responsive-bs/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../../vendors/datatables.net-scroller-bs/css/scroller.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My code where I initialize my datatable looks like this:

```
dtEdit = $('#edit-element').DataTable({
  "paging": false,
  "info": false,
  "bFilter": false,
  "bPaginate": false,
  retrieve: true,
  "processing": true,
  columns: [{
      'data': 'status'
    },

    {
      'data': '_id'
    },
    {
      'data': 'email'
    },
    {
      'data': 'role'
    },
  ],
  responsive: {
    details: {
      display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal({
        header: function ( row ) {
          var data = row.data();
          return 'Details for '+data[0]+' '+data[1];
        }
      }),
      renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll({
        tableClass: 'table'
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Any pointers please?

P.S. -> I am trying to achieve something like this:
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html

Comment: where is your list of included js files?

Comment: I have included the JS files as per the link provided

Comment: hmmm, mine is not working either. I will take another look at it tonight after work.

Comment: thanks in advance @Bindrid !

Comment: I pulled Allans stuff off his page and made it stand alone. It did not work at first but it started.  http://jsbin.com/jazime/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I then updated it to use a different data source (again, here ) http://jsbin.com/jazime/edit?html,css,js,output  so this should be able to let you compare everything

Comment: So I think your code it right, just like to see the html and the data structure if my links don't help you get up and running

Answer (score 0):

To fulfill your requirement you should follow the given steps.
1.  $(document).ready(function () );i.e. Use jquery DOM when the document is ready.
2. $('.my_button').click(function () );i.e. When you click your button modal should be loaded.
3. $('#mydatatable').DataTable(); i.e. Load the datatable at last inside  the body of $(document).ready(function ());

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        //When the button is clicked
        $('.my_button').click(function () {

            //Your code for modal 

        });<br>

        $('#mydatatable').DataTable();
    });
```